The modern search for detail and the exception
Baron Pierre de Coubertin (the father of the modern Olympic Games, which nowadays do not resemble his vision at all) had the following to say in 1929 about his contemporary generation:

They believe they are very powerful because they have great appetites, and they believe they are very wise because they have a great deal of scientific data. In reality, they are poorly prepared for the troubles ahead. Intelligence is smothered by knowledge, critical minds are debased by an overwhelming mass of facts, and adolescents are trained into the mentality of the anthill, surrounded by the artificial and the accepted, with categories and statistics, a fetish for numbers, an unhealthy search for detail and the exception.

We may nod to Coubertin's complaints, it is a very common sentiment, and on the first glance appealing.
I'm not so much interested in the issue of educational focus, e.g. favoring STEM over the humanities, but how the passage ends: "unhealthy search for detail and the exception".
Time and time again, it was the detail, the exception, that small recalcitrant thorn that just didn't want to fit into our philosophical pet theory, which planted the seeds of doubt and later brought the whole edifice down.
So, caring for details and the exception seems to be a very, very good thing. And why should it be incompatible with caring for the whole?
Even Descartes, the arch-reductionist and dissector (literally and figuratively) describes the last step of his method as to ...

... undertake such complete enumerations and such general surveys that I would be sure to have left nothing out
René Descartes: Discours de la méthode

Descartes aims to see every tree, and by this wouldn't he see the forest? Or is it already a mistake to divide and then enumerate things?
So, I don't really understand the complaints about the modern "obsession" with details and exceptions.
Is it a mere psychological claim about the limitations of the human mind? That the mind cannot both be very detail-oriented and, at the same time, holistically grasp complex matters? That we moderns pursue a very unbalanced approach?
Or is it a strange epistemological theory that truth itself is more to be found in the grand syntheses of clear-sighted observers, who are surely allowed to ignore certain small contradictory exceptions? That chopping everything up and putting it back together leads us astray?

Holistic grand views tend to overgeneralize and oversimplify. Detailed research may lose sight of its overall purpose (or of popular reception, political context). Being an expert (in any field) tends to make people cynical about cranks and too easily dismiss divergent opinions. -- What's your question? Can you give it some more focus?

@mudskipper the question is if people who extol the virtues of the holistic-synthetic over the reductionist-analytical approach make merely a claim about the restrictions of the human mind and human organizations, or make a claim about reality itself. Analogy: it is infeasible for humans to use certain mathematical proof-techniques, e.g. those that split the proof into a very extreme, but finite number of simpler sub-proofs (4-color-theorem for which only a computer-assisted proof existed). Yet, this incapability doesn't seem to say anything about the fundamental nature of mathematics.

where is the Coubertin quote from?

@Kaia Pierre this quote in its English translation I found in Fastest, Highest, Strongest: A Critique of High-Performance Sport by Rob Beamish and Ian Ritchie. For the original French quote, they refer to Olympism: Selected Writings by Coubertin himself.

Coubertin specifically mentions "unhealthy search for detail and the exception", which is just a variation on not seeing the forest for the trees. It is not that searching for detail and the exception is generally unhealthy, but rather that he saw the searching of his contemporaries specifically as unhealthy. Compare to Poincare in 1899: "In former times when one invented a new function it was for a practical purpose; today one invents them purposely to show up defects in the reasoning of our fathers and one will deduce from them only that." He turned out to be mistaken on the latter.

@Conifold sad that Coubertin didn't tell us when the search for detail and exception becomes unhealthy. That's the general problem I have with this sentiment: it provides an effortless cop-out to dodge criticism. But AFAIK, they never bothered to put ANY real thought into this matter. We just get some quotes. While defects are excusable & expected if science is just approximation (scientific anti-realism), defects hint at better approximations. And what about non-scientific reasoning? Random exceptions in moral reasoning are just bad. And discredited ethical systems are full of them.

Poincaré's quote shows how this sentiment can even befuddle a great scientist. OK, "not seeing the forest for the trees" doesn't fundamentally challenge the analytic approach, but just warns us that we humans aren't particularly good at it. Yet happily ignoring exceptions? Seems a bold belief about the nature of truth itself. Yeah, my question is muddled, but the sentiment itself is, too. As half-baked all of this is, you'd suspect there'd be some philosophical works written about it. "In Defense of Synthetic Thinking", "Accepting the Exception", etc. but there don't seem to be any.

Poincare implies a guideline of sorts, search for exceptions must have a "practical purpose", and not just be critique for critique's sake. He and Coubertin can also be charitably interpreted as calling for a constructive attitude, do not just nitpick exceptions, propose replacements of comparable generality with fewer of them, if you can. As for defense of holism, it seems to be a major theme of continental philosophy.

One of the key drives of the analytic-continental divide is the following difference in values. Continentals value grand schemes that unify diverse phenomena, even with vagueness and exceptions, much higher than precision and detail. They are not impressed by exceptions because one plainly expects them in such generality. They often see analytic focus on what those exceptions are specifically as cheap and petty nitpicking, a dirty job unworthy of philosophy that takes much less 'creative talent'.

This comes through in Derrida-Searle debates, in Deleuze's contempt for "disciples of Wittgenstein" contrasted to Whitehead, the "last great metaphysicist", in Badiou's response to criticism of his set-theoretic metaphysics by mathematicians, etc. In the end, the two sides need each other. Without detail and precision, grand schemes are air castles, but there is no path from detailing exceptions to a synthesis that does not disregard some of them along the way. How much of each is "healthy" is highly sensitive to context, I suspect, we should not expect any cogent generalities on it.

Coubertin's conservatism is very well documented and actually fed his vision for the Olympics (a venue for aristocratic young men to strive for excellence, based on a fantasized vision of classical Greece). Looking at new data and finding exceptions to the currently accepted theories is antithetic to conservatism, who usually prefers broad ideas and rejects materialism (reality has to stick to our ideas, instead of revising our ideas by adapting to reality). Based on what I know about him, IMHO it's no surprise that he found "unhealthy" the use of empirical data to challenge established models

@Conifold ok, if we grant a philosophical scheme can be enlightening or have practical value despite some rough edges here and there - I find the approach of ignoring exceptions in moral reasoning inexcusable. Ethics makes demands on others, so it's not a private endeavor. If widely adopted, there is no opt-out clause. So odd exceptions found in moral theories shouldn't be lazily dismissed by the "nitpicking" cliché. An exception that's not relevant to some "creative" philosopher might be essential to some people on the fringes of society, in an exceptional & oppressive situation.

Imagine you're buildin a massive Lego set, like the iconic Millennium Falcon from Star Wars. You've got thousands of tiny bricks scattered across the floor, and a thick instruction manual that looks more like an encyclopedia than a plaything. Now, if you were to follow Baron Pierre de Coubertin's advice and ignore the "unhealthy search for detail and the exception," you'd probably end up with a Lego creation that resembles a modern art installation more than Han Solo's beloved ship.
Picturee this - you're merrily snapping bricks together, paying no heed to the intricate diagrams and step-by-step instructions, because hey, who needs details when you've got the grand vision of the Millennium Falcon in your mind? Fast forward a few hours, and you're left with a misshapen monstrosity that wouldn't fool a Stormtrooper, let alone make the Kessel Run in less than twelve parsecs.
Now, imagine the opposite scenario - you're meticulously following every single instruction, double-checking the orientation of each tiny brick, and even accounting for the occasional misprint or omission in the manual (because let's face it, even Lego isn't immune to the occasional exception). Brick by painstaking brick, you're building a masterpiece that would make Han Solo himself proud.
The key here is that by paying attention to the details and embracing the exceptions, you're not losing sight of the bigger picture – you're ensuring that the bigger picture is accurately represented. It's like a Jedi master assembling a lightsaber; if you skip a crucial component or ignore a specific instruction, you might end up with a glorified glow stick instead of a formidable weapon.
Coubertin's sentiment, while understandable in the context of his era, fails to grasp the true power of details and exceptions. In the world of Lego (and, by extension, in the realms of science, philosophy, and life itself), it's often the smallest pieces and the most unexpected anomalies that hold the key to unlocking the grand mysteries of the universe.

On the one hand, Aristotle states in Metaphysics that

"the least deviation from the truth can lead to an enormous error" (I, 5).

Thus, attention to detail and the exceptions can prevent significant philosophical and scientific errors, ensuring that the whole is correctly understood.
On the other hand, Aristotle teaches,

“the knowledge of the whole is in a way prior to the knowledge of the parts” (Posterior Analytics, II, 19).

This does not mean the parts are to be neglected, but rather that they must be understood in their relation to the whole.
The subject is treated in a balanced manner by Thomas Aquinas Emulator, who gives justice to all the issues involved in this complicated question.
But a more intriguing reply is given by Leonard Koan who dissects the issue into its components and presents a koan for each aspect.
